# Github coding for beginners

Tags: github

I want to know about open source project.
Github is a repository where we can do this.
For that I searched a lot
got :http://www.vogella.com/training/programming/java.html link
but as I am a beginner not able to undestand.Moreover it is looking tough to me.
So, I want to know if I want to print simple "Hello World" in C or java, What simple steps I have to follow?

Comment: do you want to know more about how to become a dev or you want to know more about github?

Comment: See I want to know how to approach for coding inside github

Comment: I am just a beginner

Comment: Github is a place where you can store and show your code, so everyone else can help improve something. If you want to learn how to program, please check some "hello world" tutorial first. If you want to use Github, just create an account there and try to learn git first. Github is anyways just a remote repository for you in the terminology of Git

Comment: See I know coding in C or java, and I have registered in github. Now can u give me the link what to read and how to approach?

Comment: just check out the help page https://help.github.com/ . I would suggest you take a look at the tutorial for git first

Comment: If you just want to learn Git, there are lots of Video in Youtube as well. You can learn from them. However, I personally believe Simon mentioned the correct link and help.github.com is the best place to learn :-)